# What does it mean when a counselor asks for a copy of a passport bio

Tags: visas, passports

Thank you for your email. We are currently reviewing your case.

To be able to move forward with the visa application, please send us a copy of your current passport bio data page.

Comment: Whatcountry? What counselor?

Comment: Country: Doha Qatar    Counselor: In the embassy’s

Comment: Do you mean _consulate_?

Comment: It means that the individual needs a copy of your passport's bio page... It's not clear where you misunderstanding is.

Comment: Yes I meant that

Comment: What I’m trying to know if they ask for is that they will issue my visa or not

Comment: No one here can possibly know what is in the visa officer's mind. You can only submit the document, then wait and see if the visa is issued or refused.

Comment: Is there a time for this processing like how long it takes to make a decision